# Angular Js reference Error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am running this code, this is for square the number and it is generating some error on the console that i am not able to get it.

Error
[image]

**My Code goes here**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Angular JS Services</title>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>AngularJS Sample Application</h2>
        <div ng-app="mainApp" ng-controller="CalcController">
            <p>Enter a number: <input type="number" ng-model="number" />
            <button ng-click="square()">X<sup>2</sup></button>
            <p>Result: {{result}}</p>
        </div>


        <script>
        var mainapp = angular.module("mainApp", []);

        mainapp.factory('MathObjasService', function(a){
            var factorysrrvice = {};
            factorysrrvice.multiply = function(a, b){
                return a * b;
            }                 

            return factorysrrvice;
        });

        mainapp.service("CalSquareService", ["MathObjasService", function(MathObjasService){
            this.doubling = function(a){
                return MathObjasService.multiply(a, a);      
            }
        }]);

        mainapp.controller("CalcController", ["$scope", "CalSquareService", function($scope, CalSquareService){
            $scope.square = function(){
                $scope.result = CalSquareService.doubling($scope.number);
            }
        }]);

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Could anyone help me on this where i went wrong Please?

Comment: Remove a from argument in  mainapp.factory('MathObjasService', function(a){ ...})

Comment: If you see the console actual error is `Unknown provider: aProvider <- a <- MathObjasService <- CalSquareService`

Comment: what is the expected value of `a`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/aornfpw8/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no service named `a` which you inject in your factory

```
mainapp.factory('MathObjasService', function(a){
                                            ^^^ -> unknown provider
```

Just remove `a` from factory

try like this

```
mainapp.factory('MathObjasService', function(){});
```